# Resetting crontab file to default

Tags: cron

I've previously set a file to be crontab source file with `crontab filename`. How can I set it back to use default source? (the one that is modified with `crontab -e`)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain more? what exactly does *"set a file to be crontab source file with crontab filename"* mean? What commands or steps did you do,exactly?

Comment: I ran `crontab some_file.txt` but I totally misunderstood what it does. I explained some more in the reply to @nobody's answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try (in terminal): `$ crontab -r` where the `-r` flag removes current crontab configuration.

You can also use `$ crontab -e` and manually delete everything inside.

Other options are:

- `-l` to list crontab configuration
- `-e` to edit crontab configuration

To edit someone else's `crontab` you can use `-u` followed by the corresponding username.

Comment: Correct answer ! -- @Nina, please help yrself anytime to `$ man crontab` in terminal. Man pages are yr friend. -- Something else to be added perhaps to make above answer slightly more complete: A user `crontab` is logically created the first time a user edits its `crontab`. It is located at `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/user` where _user_ is the username know to yr system. You'll never have to go there though. Always use `$ crontab -e` to edit yr `crontab` and `$ crontab -l` to merely list its content. After removing yr `crontab` you can start again with a clean slate just typing `$ crontab -e`.

Comment: Okay this is silliness on my part. I read this http://superuser.com/a/391248 and somehow conclude that running `crontab some_file.txt` will set `some_file.txt` as the crontab source file (as in, cron would regularly scan that file instead). So it doesn't and will only reinstall crontab with `some_file.txt` content, and `crontab -e` and saving will reinstall crontab as usual (right?). Thank you for the answer!