# re-create default crontab

Tags: cron

In my attempt to make a new crontab file work on 16.04, I made the following mistake as root:

```
sudo su root
crontab /etc/cron.d/myjob
```

I realized too late that I must've changed some default crontab behaviour, ie regarding `crontab -e`. I tried to roll back like this:

```
# still as root:
crontab /etc/crontab
```

Is that the correct default setting?
If not, then what is?

PS: The [related issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793578/resetting-crontab-file-to-default) does not answer my question. The answer there only states how to remove a crontab, not how to re-generate the default Ubuntu installation settings which is what I need to know.

Comment: Thanks. Your linked issue indicates that the original root crontab was empty. Mine wasn't. I didn't add anything to it myself; I don't know what was in there; I just caught a glimpse of it with `crontab -e` before I messed up. It was a 3 weeks old 16.04 Unity installation. It must've been the one that ships with the installation; is that `/etc/crontab`?

Comment: Here is the contents of `/etc/crontab`: https://gist.github.com/ellvtr/c9f804e277d8bd3683766115c68a7877

Answer (score 3):

Cron utilizes two, quite independent sets of [crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) files.

1. One of them is **public** ([system-wide](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html#Jobs_in_/etc/cron.d/)), located in `/etc`. It includes `/etc/crontab` and the files in `/etc/cron.d`.
   The [file you linked](https://gist.github.com/ellvtr/c9f804e277d8bd3683766115c68a7877) looks much like the default `/etc/crontab`. If you have got this contents in your `/etc/crontab` file, keep it.
2. The other includes a **private** file for each user. Their actual location is `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` but this folder is not accessible by normal means. These crontab files shall be accessed and modified using the [`crontab`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html) *command*.
   A user’s crontab (including root, accessed using `sudo crontab <option>`) does not exist by default. When you issue `crontab -e` and have no crontab file for given user, the command brings a template with no scheduled commands, just descriptive comments. The file is saved only if you modify the template.
   To reset this one to the default state (i.e. **r**emove it), use the command:

   ```
   crontab -r
   ```

Comment: The user crontab is functionally empty but contains informative comments at the start, iirc.

Comment: @muru You are almost right. If you open the empty crontab using `crontab` command, you get some placeholder comments. However, they aren’t stored in the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` until you save your own crontab.

Comment: `sudo contab -e` was not empty before I messed it up. It had actual jobs in there, not just the standard comments. If it was empty by the Ubuntu installation - I only got a short glimpse of it. I assume some applications have added root cronjobs after the installation then.

Comment: @JonasEllehauge the root user's crontab is empty by default. Any packages that need to run cronjobs use the `/etc/cron.*` directories. No package edits the root user's crontab.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. There were some entries in mine and I didn't add them manually. Here's what's in there now `17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly /n 25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ) [+more anacron entries]`. Looks like anaconda added some. The first one looks like a system entry to me.

Comment: @JonasEllehauge The lines you reported should be in `/etc/crontab`, not in root’s crontab. Do you really get them when you call `sudo crontab -l`? They shouldn’t even work due to the extra field with the username that only applies to the _public_ crontabs. And [anacron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron) is unrelated to [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)).

Comment: Yes, I get that when as root I run `crontab -l` and it happens to be identical to `cat /etc/crontab`. Possibly because: Before I posted here, I ran `crontab /etc/crontab` to try to restore whatever I got a glimpse of before I messed up.

Comment: I agree. That’s why I recommended you to run `crontab -r` to reset it.